# Data attribute in XML View elements

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to add data attributes to elements in a XML View as below:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    <VBox data-help-id="Some.String.Here">
        ...
    </VBox>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

but couldn't find how to do it, unless I assign them via Controller.

Tried using CustomData namespace, but it only adds data, without adding the HTML attribute to the DOM element.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only influence the attributes written to the DOM using the standard control properties. If the standard properties don't provide you with a way to set the right HTML attibutes, and you still want to get your own HTML attributes in the DOM, you'll need to subclass the control and write your own renderer. When you write your own renderer, you have full control over what's written to the DOM.

You can find more information on writing custom controls in [Step 34](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db.html) of the SAPUI5 Walkthrough.

Answer (score 4):

actually you can do something very close and associate data to your xmlView. This is available for xml views and more. Check this url for more details: [Custom Data - Attaching Data Objects to Controls](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/91/f0c3ee6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm)

What you would need to do is add a custom namespace to your xmlView:

```
xmlns:dataHelp="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
```

...

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    <VBox dataHelp:id="Some.String.Here" id="myBox"
        ...
    </VBox>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

you are then able to set and consume this attribute in your binding and javascript/controller/event handler:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("myBox").data("id") // = Some.String.Here
```